# multiple Async/await JS function

Tags: async-await, sails.js

In my controller, the fn function executes return.suucess() before my variables are properly defined. In this case, the ytb  object.
The sails.log of "items" is correct, but "ytb" did not return.

I also tried with Promise.then, and .all. Also, with async.each() and removing the await inside this function.

```
    fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

        var url = require('url');
        var items = await Collection.find({});

        _.each(items, async item => {
            if (item.youtube_url) {
                var ytbUrl = item.youtube_url;
                var regexBaseUrlYtb = new RegExp('(https://www.youtube.com/channel/)');

                if (regexBaseUrlYtb.test(ytbUrl)) {
                    var ytbIdChannel = ytbUrl.replace(regexBaseUrlYtb, '');
                    var ytbChannel = await sails.helpers.youtubeApi(ytbIdChannel);
                    item.ytb = {};
                    Object.assign(item.ytb, ytbChannel);
                } 
            }
            sails.log('items: ', item)
        });
        return  exits.success({
            items
        });
    }
```

I expect that the ytb object will also be passed with the object item at the view, but the items object is passed without the ytb object.

Also, in general, I expect the return exits.success() runs only once the function finished

Thanks.